# Ошибка после компиляции

Tags: android

Не могу понять в чем ошибка

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener  {

    protected android.widget.ProgressBar ProgressBar;
    String scoreStr;//Рекорд
    int exScore;//Рекорд
    long time1, time2, timefinal; //Переменные для принятия и отображения времени
    private Calendar mStartTime;
    int chislo1;
    String chislo;
    String btnarray1;//
    int[] btnarray = new int[4];//4 разных числа для кнопок
    int level = 0, answer = 0, operator = 0, operand1 = 0,
            operand2 = 0;
    int progress = 0;
    private final int ADD_OPERATOR = 0, SUBTRACT_OPERATOR = 1,
            MULTIPLY_OPERATOR = 2, DIVIDE_OPERATOR = 3;
    private String[] operators = {"+", "-", "x", "/"};

    private int[][] levelMin = {{1, 11, 21}, {1, 5, 10}, {2, 5, 10},
            {2, 3, 5}};
    private int[][] levelMax = {{10, 25, 50}, {10, 20, 30}, {5, 10, 15},
            {15, 60, 120}};

    private Random random;

    private TextView question, answerTxt, scoreTxt;

    private Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();//Первая переменная для принятия времени
        mStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        final boolean paused = false;
        final ProgressBar progressBar;
        progress = 0;
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(200);//Макс знач
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Переносим сюда старый код
                if (!paused) {
                    progress++;//Progress прибавление прогесса
                    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                    if (progress > 199) {
                        proigral();
                    }
                    if (progress < progressBar.getMax()) {//До макс. значения прогресс бара
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 32);// Говорим Handler запустить эту функцию(this) через 0,65 сек.
                    }
                }
            }


        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);//Активация потока
        thread.start();//Старт этого потока

        answerTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2) ;
        time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();//принятие текущего времени.
        scoreTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);//Обработа нажатия для всех кнопок
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);//Обработа нажатия для всех кнопок
        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);//Обработа нажатия для всех кнопок
        btn4.setOnClickListener(this);//Обработа нажатия для всех кнопок
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int passedLevel = extras.getInt("level", -1);
            if (passedLevel >= 0)
                level = passedLevel;
        }
        random = new Random();//Переменная для рандома
        chooseQuestion();//Вызвать создание примеров
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);//Загрузка анимации

        if (view.getId() == R.id.btn1) {
            //we have an answer
            if (btnarray[0] == answer) {
                //correct
                pravOtvet();//Метод при правильном ответе
            } else {
                //incorrect
                btn1.startAnimation(shake);//Активация анимации
                proigral();//Метод переходящий на другую активити
            }
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btn2) {
            //we have an answe
            if (btnarray[1] == answer) {
                //correct
                pravOtvet();//Метод при правильном ответе
            } else {
                //incorrect
                btn2.startAnimation(shake);//Активация анимации
                proigral();//Метод переходящий на другую активити
            }
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btn3) {
            //we have an answer
            if (btnarray[2] == answer) {
                pravOtvet();//Метод при правильном ответе
            } else {
                btn3.startAnimation(shake);//Активация анимации
                proigral();//Метод переходящий на другую активити

            }
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btn4) {
            //we have an answer
            if (btnarray[3] == answer) {
                pravOtvet();//Метод при правильном ответе
            } else {
                btn4.startAnimation(shake);//Активация анимации
                proigral();//Метод переходящий на другую активити
            }
        }
    }


    public void pravOtvet()//Метод при правильном ответе
    {
        exScore = getScore();
        progress = 0;//Обнуление прогресса
        //correct
        scoreTxt.setText("Score: " + (exScore + 1));
        chooseQuestion();//Вызвать создание примеров
    }


    private void chooseQuestion() {//СОЗДАНЕ РАНДОМНЫХ ПРИМЕРОВ
        // get a questionСоздание примеров
        operator = random.nextInt(operators.length);
        operand1 = getOperand();
        operand2 = getOperand();

        if (operator == SUBTRACT_OPERATOR) {
            while (operand2 > operand1) {
                operand1 = getOperand();
                operand2 = getOperand();
            }
        } else if (operator == DIVIDE_OPERATOR) {
            while ((((double) operand1 / (double) operand2) % 1 > 0)
                    || (operand1 == operand2)) {
                operand1 = getOperand();
                operand2 = getOperand();
            }
        }

        switch (operator) {//Выбор оператора.
            case ADD_OPERATOR:
                answer = operand1 + operand2;
                chislo1 = operand1 + operand2;
                chislo = Integer.toString(chislo1);
                randomFeed:
                for (int i = 0; i < btnarray.length; ) {//создаем рандомные числа
                    int c = random.nextInt(4);
                    btnarray[i] = c + chislo1 - 1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                        if (btnarray[j] == btnarray[i]) {
                            continue randomFeed;
                        }
                    }
                    ++i;
                }

                btn1.setText(Integer.toString(btnarray[0]));//Присваем кнопке 1 значение числа
                btn2.setText(Integer.toString(btnarray[1]));//Присваем кнопке 1 значение числа
                btn3.setText(Integer.toString(btnarray[2]));//Присваем кнопке 1 значение числа
                btn4.setText(Integer.toString(btnarray[3]));//Присваем кнопке 1 значение числа

                break;
            case SUBTRACT_OPERATOR:
                answer = operand1 - operand2;
                chislo1 = (operand1 - operand2);
                chislo = Integer.toString(chislo1);
                randomFeed:
                for (int i = 0; i < btnarray.length; ) {
                    int c = random.nextInt(4);
                    btnarray[i] = c + chislo1 - 1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                        if (btnarray[j] == btnarray[i]) {
                            continue randomFeed;
                        }
                    }
                    ++i;
                }

                btn1.setText(Integer.toString(btnarray[0]));//Присваем кнопке 1 значение числа
                btn2.setText(Integer.toString(btnarray[1]));//Присваем кнопке 1 значение числа
                btn3.setText(Integer.toString(btnarray[2]));//Присваем кнопке 1 значение числа
                btn4.setText(Integer.toString(btnarray[3]));//Присваем кнопке 1 значение числа
                break;
            case MULTIPLY_OPERATOR:
                answer = operand1 * operand2;
                chislo1 = (operand1 * operand2);
                chislo = Integer.toString(chislo1);
                randomFeed:
                for (int i = 0; i < btnarray.length; ) {
                    int c = random.nextInt(4);
                    btnarray[i] = c + chislo1 - 1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                        if (btnarray[j] == btnarray[i]) {
                            continue randomFeed;
                        }
                    }
                    ++i;
                }

                btn1.setText(Integer.toString(btnarray[0]));//Присваем кнопке 1 значение числа
                btn2.setText(Integer.toString(btnarray[1]));//Присваем кнопке 1 значение числа
                btn3.setText(Integer.toString(btnarray[2]));//Присваем кнопке 1 значение числа
                btn4.setText(Integer.toString(btnarray[3]));//Присваем кнопке 1 значение числа
                break;
            case DIVIDE_OPERATOR:
                chislo1 = operand1 / operand2;
                chislo = Integer.toString(chislo1);
                answer = operand1 / operand2;
                randomFeed:
                for (int i = 0; i < btnarray.length; ) {
                    int c = random.nextInt(4);
                    btnarray[i] = c + chislo1 - 1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                        if (btnarray[j] == btnarray[i]) {
                            continue randomFeed;
                        }
                    }
                    ++i;
                }
                btn1.setText(Integer.toString(btnarray[0]));//Присваем кнопке 1 значение числа
                btn2.setText(Integer.toString(btnarray[1]));//Присваем кнопке 1 значение числа
                btn3.setText(Integer.toString(btnarray[2]));//Присваем кнопке 1 значение числа
                btn4.setText(Integer.toString(btnarray[3]));//Присваем кнопке 1 значение числа
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        question.setText(operand1 + " " + operators[operator] + " " + operand2);
        int chisla = operand1 + operand2;
    }

    private int getOperand() {
        // return operand number
        return random.nextInt(levelMax[operator][level]
                - levelMin[operator][level] + 1)
                + levelMin[operator][level];
    }

    private int getScore() {//Рекорд
        scoreStr = scoreTxt.getText().toString();
        return parseInt(scoreStr.substring(scoreStr.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1));
    }

    public void proigral() {

        Calendar nowTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        long secs = (nowTime.getTimeInMillis() - mStartTime.getTimeInMillis()) / 1000;
        progress = 201;
        Intent restartIntent;
        restartIntent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, Restart.class);
        restartIntent.putExtra("secs", String.valueOf(secs));
        restartIntent.putExtra("scheat", Integer.toString(exScore));
        startActivity(restartIntent);
    }
}
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.example.imatematik02, PID: 10222
>                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.imatematik02/com.example.imatematik02.GameActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                 at
>   com.example.imatematik02.GameActivity.chooseQuestion(GameActivity.java:277)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.example.imatematik02.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:104)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: У вас NPE. Проверьте ID

Comment: Не знаю как правильно это сделать. Подскажите ?

Comment: Если `Exception` внимательнее читать, можно увидеть строку `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`. Явно понятно, что attemt (пытаемся) to invoke virtual method (вызвать метод) `void ...setText(java.lang...)` (под названием setText) `on a null object` (на твой TextView, который NULL, что означает забыл указать какой именно TextView ты используешь). Таких вопросов на stackoverflow и в интернете триллиард.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы забыли проинициализировать `TextView question`, он у вас равен null

А в методе chooseQuestion() вы пытаетесь положить в него текст

```
question.setText(operand1 + " " + operators[operator] + " " + operand2);
```

Вот и возникает ошибка